# Changing .NET 4 Runtime Activation Policy For Dll Within C++ Code

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c#-4.0, fortran

We've developed a C# 4.0 module that needs to be accessed from an unmanaged C++ program (as well as a Fortran program). The DLL gets loaded correctly and the method is available to the C++ program, but an exception gets thrown when calling the method that points to the C# code. For a visualization:

```
[Unmanaged C++ / Fortran Projects]  
  -> controller.dll (unmanaged C++ within the C++ project)    
     -> managed_wrapper.dll (managed C++ within the C# project)
        -> C# 4.0 Project
```

The exception gets thrown when the controller attempts to call the managed C++ (using .NET 4.0 framework).

My suspicions are that the following configuration needs to be applied, as we encountered an error previously when [creating a proof of concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124294/debugging-managed-net-code-called-from-unmanaged-c):

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I applied it correctly for the aforementioned proof of concept, but that was on a stand-alone console application. Since the unmanaged C++ program is huge and the settings are not universal for every module, I'm unable to create a `MyApplication.exe.config` file with the above configuration and call it day.

My question is this: Is it possible to apply that configuration to a specific DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, this is not possible.

The issue is that, the configuration setting you need to apply (`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`) is basically saying "for this entire application, no matter what the assembly requests, use CLR 4 instead.

If you *could* apply it to a single DLL, you'd be violating the goals here - since the goal is to force all assemblies to use CLR 4.

---

Edit:

After further study, there is actually a way to do this in some limited scenarios.  I [posted about this on my blog](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/), but basically, you can use the CLR Hosting API to get some access to setting this from within a library.

Comment: @Chuck: If you need a mixed mode (C++/CLI) .NET 4 program, to my knowledge, you **must** change the app.Config for the application itself.  It's incredibly annoying, and I really hope I'm wrong.  (We went through this, and I was forced to back port a huge code base to .NET 3.5 for exactly this reason - I couldn't add this policy to the application without breaking another [3rd party] plugin, so I was forced to back port to 3.5)

Comment: Oh jeez. Every bit of research I've done suggests the same thing, but I was hoping a magic solution existed. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Chuck: As I said, I seriously hope I'm wrong - but everything I've been able to find (and try) fails :(

Comment: Aye, same here. We'll just revert to .NET 3.5 as you said (It's not a gigantic project) and eliminate it altogether. I plan on attempting to get an official response from Microsoft about it, though.

Comment: @Chuck: One thing to note - this *should* only be required if you're application may load a pre-.NET 4 mixed mode assembly.  If it's only going to load your .NET 4 wrappers, this is likely not the problem. I'd recommend reading this - http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,ecc34c3c-be44-4422-86b7-900900e451f9.aspx

Comment: @Chuck: Just came up with something very interesting.  You might want to see my edit, and read: http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, we've already decided to rewrite the library in C++, but I'll definitely keep your solution in mind should I ever encounter this again.